# Derivision of a transfer function from a block diagram with gain blocks

Tags: control-theory

I have derived the transfer function G(s) shown in the image.

I now need to work out the closed loop transfer function for the entire system and I can select my own values of k but I am doubting my method.

Is it as simple as this;

$$\frac{k(s)G(s)*2.51}{1+k(s)(G(s)*2.51}$$

Or am I mixing up concepts?

Comment: You need one more 2.51 because pre-gain multiplying the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule for SISO systems is the following:

Let $G_1(s)$ be the transfer function of the feedforward path and $G_2(s)$ be the transfer function of the feedback path. Then the closed loop transfer function for negative feedback is:

$$G_{cl}(s) = \frac{G_1(s)}{1+G_1(s)G_2(s)}$$

In your case, it is possible to move the 2.51 into the loop since it is present in both routes before the sum. This means that 
$$G_1(s) = \frac{2.51*0.36*K(s)}{s(s+1.95)}$$ and $$G_2(s) = 1$$.

In this case it is often helpful to apply the following formula: 
$$G_1(s) = \frac{N(s)}{D(s)} $$
$$G_{cl}(s) = \frac{N(s)}{N(s) + D(s)}$$

Comment: if you choose $k = 5$ you end up with 2.51*0.36*5 which is 4.518. Taking the second rule this means that the closed loop transfer function should be $$\frac{4.518}{s² + 1.95s + 4.518}$$.